# The meaning of the set expression "tel jour ..., tel autre jour ..."?

Tags: expressions

> **Tel jour**, consacrez-vous à des mots de vocabulaire à apprendre, **tel autre jour**, faites des exercices de mise en pratique **et tel autre**, rédigez un texte en anglais pour vous resservir de vos acquis…

I assume this is a variant form of "un jour...,  un autre ..." or "des fois..., d'autres fois ...", but I wonder how they differ in meaning, exactly?

Also, is it possible to use other nouns in the expression "tel + noun ... tel autre + noun ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In French, we use **tel** to take an example without actually precising this example. It has the same meaning as what you said, but in my opinion, it's better for illustrating.

I would say it means the same as **Ce jour en particulier**, "this particular day".

Definition from the French Larousse dictionary: http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tel_telle/77019

> Devant un nom sans article, indique une personne, une chose, sans les définir précisément : *On a fait telle chose, tel jour à tel endroit.*
>
> [English] In front of a noun without any article, indicates a person, a thing, without defining them precisely.

This definition answers your second question: it is indeed possible to use this structure to designate any noun, even though it's mainly used for time (days, hours), people, actions and locations. It might sound a bit weird with an object, but it is grammatically correct, for example:

> Je prends telle fourchette, tel jour à telle heure.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind *tel(le)* is that you imply a specificity of the upcoming noun or group.

> Telle personne ne peut se joindre à nous.
>
> [ENG] Such person cannot join us.

This sentence has no particular interest without extra information (pointing at someone, a description of a person, ...). The expected information might be located in a sentence before the one using *tel(le)*.